# KnockoutJS check if on textbox is greater than another textbox

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am new to KnockoutJS and I am having some trouble with validation. I have two textboxes and I am trying to validate to ensure that textbox1 input value is greater than textbox2 input value.

```
<input type="number" id="tbLow" name="tbLow" data-bind="value: model.tbLow"/>
<input type="number" id="tbHigh" name="tbHigh" data-bind="value: model.tbHigh"/>
```

this isthe validation for tbLow:

```
self.model.tbLow.extend({
    min: 1,
    max: 999999,
    maxLength: 6,
    validation: { validator: greaterThan, 
                  message: 'tbHigh must be larger than Car tbLow.', 
                  params: tbHigh }

});
```

here is the validation function:

```
var greaterThan = function (tbLow, tbHigh ) {
    return CarNumberHigh > CarNumberLow;
}
```

I am not able to get the value for `tbHigh`... 
Any ideas??

Comment: Have you used the getter function somewhere that I am missing?  tgHigh()

Comment: what getter function? - the other validations are working well (min, maxlength etc.)

Comment: If you need to 'get' the value of tbHigh and it is an observable, when you reference it in your view model you need to use the getter function tbHigh().  I don't use the validation plugin that much but try changing your params to params: tbHigh()

Comment: so i should change the validation function?
    validation: { validator: greaterThan, message: 'Car Number High must be larger than Car Number Low.', params: tbHigh() }

is throwing an error : TypeError: CarNumberHigh is not a function

Comment: Have you tried debugging and seeing the values being passed into your greaterThan function?  Most likely you just need to execute you tbHigh observable

Comment: yeah, when I debug in firebug there is no value for tbHigh... there is the correct value for tbLow
how do I execute tbHigh observable

Comment: has tbHigh been declared? or have you declared tbLow with the extend before it?

Comment: both have been declared:
       self.model.tbLow.extend({
        min: 1,
        max: 999999,
        maxLength: 6,
        //areSame: { params: selfCarNumberHigh, message: "testMessage" }
        validation: { validator: greaterThan, message: 'Car Number High must be larger than Car Number Low.', params: tbHigh() }
    });
    self.model.tbHigh.extend({
        min: 1,
        max: 999999,
        maxLength: 12,

    });

Comment: For reference it is not executing the observable, it's utilizing the getter function.

Comment: sounds like @PWKad is correct.  Try in your greaterThan to get the value from tbHigh by using tbHigh()

Comment: As mentioned above, when I change the function 

var greaterThan = function (tbLow, tbHigh) {
    return tbHigh() > tbLow;
}

I get the following error: TypeError: CarNumberHigh is not a function

Comment: ok, getting confused a little, would you be able to get a jsfiddle of this running for me to have a look at?  not sure what you are trying to achieve with using tbHigh, and then this CarNumberHigh variable

Comment: Your error is from your function. You're not using the parameters you're passing in:
var greaterThan = function (tbLow, tbHigh ) {
    return tbHigh > tbLow;
}

Answer (score 0):

An extender wraps an observable.  Are you setting the value of `model.tbLow` to the result of the observable.extend() function?

Your code should look like this:

```
self.model.tbLow = self.model.tbLow.extend({ ... });
```

Or if you extend it from within your model...

```
this.tbLow = ko.observable(...).extend({ ... });
```

Did you write that validation extender yourself or are you using something you found?  Can you post or link to the code for that?  Otherwise we don't know if you're using it properly, we can't know what the 'greaterThan' function is being sent.